# how to read softhsm keys

Tags: pkcs#11, hsm, softhsm

I am using softhsm2 to generate keys/tokens, and I don't know how I can read my keys value. I am using this command to get the hsm content but it doesn't give a lot of details :

pkcs11-tool --module /usr/lib64/pkcs11/libsofthsm2.so -l -t

is there any other tools to manage sofhsm ?

Thank you!

Comment: Try to reach the goal from other side of [SoftHSM](https://github.com/opendnssec/SoftHSMv2#backup)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have not installed the pkcs11-tool in your machine and probably your HSM is hosted in a remote machine. If this the case plesae check [Expose SoftHSM library to the code running in host machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56756141/expose-softhsm-library-to-the-code-running-in-host-machine) or https://github.com/rbroggi/softhsm-daemon